# Deploying a Flask using mod_wsgi: I get an error "Unable to Open Database File" from error.log

Tags: flask, mod-wsgi

I have installed mod_wsgi and am currently working to deploy a test app. The issue stems from the application unable to read from the database. If I do not use mod_wsgi the test app works.

Here is my testapp.wsgi

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.7

import logging
import sys
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/TestApp/TestApp/')

from testapp import app as application
application.secret_key = "anything you wish"
```

Here is my TestApp.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName 172.28.103.40
        WSGIDaemonProcess testapp user=www-data group=www-data threads=5
        WSGIScriptAlias /testApp/var/www/html/TestApp/TestApp$

        <Directory /var/www/html/TestApp/TestApp>
                WSGIProcessGroup testapp
                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

my database directory

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data      www-data  4096 Nov  1 11:23 db
```

my database file

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data      www-data 237568 Nov  1 11:23 shieldcampus.db
```

I realize that full 777 access is not required but I wanted to see if setting the permissions to 777 would work and it did not.

The exact error in the error log is

```
[Thu Nov 14 10:53:35.501047 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 3760] [client 172.19.90.16:60233]     con = sqlite3.connect("db/testapp.db")
[Thu Nov 14 10:53:35.501062 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 3760] [client 172.19.90.16:60233] OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

One thing I am noticing is the IP address from the error log is not the IP address I am using to access my site.

My site IP is 172.28.103.40
The IP being used with WSGI for this call is 172.19.90.16:60233

Could this be a clue to what is going on? If not is there a disconnect I have missed. Being new to mod_wsgi it's possible I may have missed something when it comes to database setup with mod_wsgi. I didn't see any on the documentation.

Also this is a local server, not public. Not sure if that makes a difference.

Edit: flask application code

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello world!"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Can you please share your flask application code. Also, how is the app deployed is it in a separate server from where you are trying to access

Comment: The app is deployed in a separate server. A raspberry pi to be exact running Apache2. What is really weird is that this was working this morning. Then again, without changing anything it stopped working. Perhaps restarting the server is what caused it.

Comment: it appears that if I run this locally on the localhost, updating the server name in the .conf file, it works. Therefore the issue lies in accessing from another terminal through the hostname of my server. Interesting. I am experiencing another error however when I click a link and it is routed through flask I lose the WSGIScriptAlias redirect folder. That is I run localhost/testApp, it redirects to localhost/testApp/login and works. I click a link and it redirects to localhost/dashboard not localhost/testApp/dashboard. This is definitely a different question though.